# error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/title_gizmos')

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I am following this tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking
And I can't get it to work. This is the declared manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:compileSdkVersion="28" android:compileSdkVersionCodename="9" android:installLocation="auto" package="io.kodular.ontstudios.Deeplinks_Test" platformBuildVersionCode="28" platformBuildVersionName="9">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <application android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="Deeplinks_Test" android:name="com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:supportsRtl="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:name="io.kodular.ontstudios.Deeplinks_Test.Screen1" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
                <data android:scheme="http"
                      android:host="www.example.com"
                      android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
                <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
                <data android:scheme="example"
                      android:host="gizmos" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="io.kodular.app.VERSION" android:value="1.4C.4-Eagle"/>
        <provider android:authorities="io.kodular.ontstudios.Deeplinks_Test.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
        <meta-data android:name="Kodular_RCWTFYP-BYDNKHMWRIT-DNLATT" android:value="_d4705d7c44acc5bd4f7b41c83f38a3b7.d4705d7c44acc5bd4f7b41c83f38a3b7-1591708822~IHyiEtMYRvDgxXbt4rhOSnOCkopeFofjrENFozlMYAzosQQBVH5WqkA1OStZfxta_"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And, the compiler shows:

```
I: Using Apktool 2.4.1
I: Copying C:\Users\ONT Studios\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-editor-studio\apk\{73264eb7-54f0-4471-a5b1-8e1585e25763} classes.dex file...
I: Copying C:\Users\ONT Studios\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-editor-studio\apk\{73264eb7-54f0-4471-a5b1-8e1585e25763} classes2.dex file...
I: Building resources...
W: fakeLogOpen(/dev/log_crash) failed
W: fakeLogOpen(/dev/log_stats) failed
W: fakeLogOpen(/dev/log_crash) failed
W: fakeLogOpen(/dev/log_stats) failed
W: fakeLogOpen(/dev/log_crash) failed
W: fakeLogOpen(/dev/log_stats) failed
W: C:\Users\ONT Studios\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-editor-studio\apk\{73264eb7-54f0-4471-a5b1-8e1585e25763}\AndroidManifest.xml:13: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/title_gizmos').
W: 
W: C:\Users\ONT Studios\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-editor-studio\apk\{73264eb7-54f0-4471-a5b1-8e1585e25763}\AndroidManifest.xml:16: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/filter_view_http_gizmos').
W: 
W: C:\Users\ONT Studios\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-editor-studio\apk\{73264eb7-54f0-4471-a5b1-8e1585e25763}\AndroidManifest.xml:26: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/filter_view_example_gizmos').
W: 
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\ONTSTU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_6559922005293012339.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 19, --target-sdk-version, 28, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.0, --no-version-vectors, -F, C:\Users\ONTSTU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL4214939072774050782.tmp, -e, C:\Users\ONTSTU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL4459946816309254913.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\ONT Studios\AppData\Local\apk-editor-studio\frameworks\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\ONT Studios\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-editor-studio\apk\{73264eb7-54f0-4471-a5b1-8e1585e25763}\res, -M, C:\Users\ONT Studios\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-editor-studio\apk\{73264eb7-54f0-4471-a5b1-8e1585e25763}\AndroidManifest.xml]
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, this is my first time editing the manifest.
How can I correctly add deeplinks?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `strings.xml` file, have you added the string with key `title_gizmos`? If not you'll have to add it like this:

```
<string name="title_gizmos">Gizmos</string>
```

***Updated answer:***

You can find the `strings.xml` file in either `/res/values/strings.xml` or use double shift keyboard shortcut to open the finder and search for `strings.xml`.

*More information about resource files [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource).*

Comment: Sorry for being dumb, but where can I find it 
https://prnt.sc/swl63w

Comment: There is plenty of them. I will try to add it to all of them and see how it goes

Comment: This is the log now:

Comment: @ONTStudios You can either find it in `res/values/strings.xml` or double tap on right-shift button on keyboard and type `strings.xml`. You can check more information [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource). 
I have updated the answer also.

Comment: Works, but I can't open the app now

Comment: What I mean is, the open button on the app is disabled